# Load raw data from a file without dropping backslash characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding

I have a file that contains the following content (simplified version that demonstrates the problem):

```
"abc\"def"
```

I would like to load the literal content of the file into a table without any mangling of the data. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
CREATE TABLE file_content (content text);
COPY file_content FROM '/path/to/test.txt';
```

The resulting line in the table is:

```
"abc"def"
```

In other words, the backslash was silently dropped/ignored. I've tried the copy with different encodings (UTF8, LATIN1, SQL_ASCII) without any change in behavior.

Also, the ESCAPE and QUOTE options seemed promising at first, but they are only for COPY ... TO.

Is there a way to load raw data from a file without the mangling? I'm using version PostgreSQL version 9.4.6.

Comment: What is the setting of `standard_conforming_strings` on your server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is set to "on".

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `\` to `\\`. You can use `sed` for that:

`sed -i -- 's/\\/\\\\/g' import.file`

**Please make sure you have reviewed your data and backuped it before performing operation above.**

Comment: I don't have that option. The files are shared with other programs which correctly load the raw data without mangling it. Also, I want to be able to load the file without external pre-processing.